# How to add a 'default using' to all cshtml pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating my first MVC.Net application and I find myself including `@using Gideon.Core.Mvc;` on almost every page. **Is it possible to add it by default to all pages?**

<sub>In Asp.Net I'm able to add default stuff for controls to the web.config, hopefully it can be done for MVC.Net as well.</sub>

Comment: Do the pages share a common master page? Can you include it there?

Comment: This is all controlled by the web.config, typically the one in your Views folder. I don't have any code to hand (hence not an answer), but you should see the namespaces. Add yours; all done.

Comment: @Foovanadil razor has layouts, not masters, and I don't think that works

Comment: I admittedly used the wrong term, I meant layouts. I was under the impression that layouts and master pages are very similar and are basically enabling the same scenarios? Am I missing a fundamental difference between the two? (aside from  site wide includes not working, I wasn't sure that would work anyways)

Comment: Maybe in the _AppStart.cshtml file? Or the _SiteLayout.cshtml file...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add them in the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` section in `Views/Web.config`.

Here is the default:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 9):

Add them in the `Views/Web.config`. Add your namespace to the bottom:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            <add namespace="Gideon.Core.Mvc" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 4):

For .Net Core Users if you create a vanilla web project you can import default namespaces by adding the

```
_ViewImports.cshtml
```

File within your Pages folder.

And define your default namespaces within.

```
@using test
@namespace test.Pages
```

Comment: Great! Saved me a lot of searching.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is high on google, let me add an alternative solution which is area compatible.

Create a new class called `PreApplicationStart` (or any other name you want).

```
public class PreApplicationStart
{
    public static void InitializeApplication()
    {
        System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebCodeRazorHost.AddGlobalImport("insert.your.namespace.here");
    }
}
```

In `Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs` add following line:

```
[assembly: System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PreApplicationStart), "InitializeApplication")]
```

With this the namespace is available in every view in the project (including views within areas). Adding the namespace to `web.config` has this flaw, that if you use areas, you end up having to add the namespace to every `web.config` file in each area.