# The type or namespace name 'Resource' could not be found

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a resource.resx file where i have listed the variables in key value pair. In "cs" part of my project the resources is recognized.
But in "razor" part in my "cshtml" file i get error. "The type or namespace name 'Resource' could not be found". What is the correct way of using resource in "razor" code?

```
@using Resource
....
...
<td>Name <a href="@Resource.Name"></a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your c# code. Click on `Resource` class (go to class definition - you need just press F12 when your cursor stays on class name). And check namespace of this class. Put this namespace in `@using` section. 
But I recommend you to put definition of this namespace in pages by default. [You can read there how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023576/182344)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had to add the correct namespace. Now it works.

Comment: @user1651888 If my post help you, could you mark it as answer :).

Answer (score 0):

I just created new MVC project. Added `Resource.resx` file with `String1` property. Build it. All I had to was calling `@Resource.String1` in a view, without using `@using` directive or adding a namespace.

```
<h2>@Resource.String1</h2>
```